# I have reponse data from API and need extract specific columns from nested lists and data frame and loop through it in R

Tags: r, dataframe, api

** I have here a response from an API call. I need to be able to extract the column I need from this and be able to loop through the dates. How do I do this, I'm new to are and not sure how to extract data when there are nested list and data frames.**

The is what I get from api response when I

`dimensions <- rawToChar(dimensions)`
`dimensions <- fromJSON(dimensions)`

`dput(dimensions)`

```
structure(list(dates = structure(list(from = "2021-09-30", to = "2021- 
11-07"), .Names = c("from",
"to")), countries = structure(list(key = c("AE", "AT", "BE",
"CH", "CY", "DE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GG", "IE", "IM", "IN",
"IT", "JE", "MT", "PT", "UN", "US"), label = c("United Arab 
 Emirates",
"Austria", "Belgium", "Switzerland", "Cyprus", "Germany", "Spain",
"Finland", "France", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern 
Ireland",
"Guernsey", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "India", "Italy", "Jersey",
"Malta", "Portugal", "Unknown", "United States of America")), .Names 
 = 
c("key",
"label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 20L)), formats = 
structure(list(
key = "thumbnail", label = "Thumbnail"), .Names = c("key",
"label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), integration_types = 
structure(list(
key = "standard_integration", label = "Standard Integration"), .Names 
 = 
c("key",
"label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), asset_types = 
structure(list(
key = "WEB", label = "Web"), .Names = c("key", "label"), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = 1L),
assets = structure(list(asset_id = c("df21815c-fbb3-4c0a-a445- 
149d1f744c9b",
"abc4d10a-7704-4cbb-b00f-3d97c12ddd69", "38146ea6-eaa8-437c-a799- 
c8b9e4e9b811",
"01d49fb2-127b-4dc1-b0c7-e16fc6013316"), asset_key = c("OGY- 
F930DBE00E4C",
"OGY-405A9DFBA8DD", "OGY-24AC9F861883", "OGY-BB66F3DDA19D"
), app_api_key = c(305636L, 305967L, 305966L, 305965L), name = 
c("Closer",
"empireonline.com", "heatworld.com", "motherandbaby.co.uk"
), bundle = c("closeronline.co.uk", "empireonline.com", 
"heatworld.com",
"motherandbaby.co.uk"), asset_type = structure(list(key = c("WEB",
"WEB", "WEB", "WEB"), label = c("Web", "Web", "Web", "Web"
)), .Names = c("key", "label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA,
4L)), icon_url = 
c("https://closeronline.co.uk/static/assets/favicons/favicon.ico",
"https://empireonline.com/static/assets/favicons/favicon.ico",
"https://heatworld.com/static/assets/favicons/favicon.ico",
"https://motherandbaby.co.uk/static/assets/favicons/favicon.ico"
), organization = structure(list(id = c("f2df67e0-76d0-47d7-9d2e- 
e1b205ad3f5d",
"f2df67e0-76d0-47d7-9d2e-e1b205ad3f5d", "f2df67e0-76d0-47d7-9d2e- 
e1b205ad3f5d",
"f2df67e0-76d0-47d7-9d2e-e1b205ad3f5d"), name = c("Bauer Media Group 
UK",
"Bauer Media Group UK", "Bauer Media Group UK", "Bauer Media Group 
UK"
), status = c("ACTIVE", "ACTIVE", "ACTIVE", "ACTIVE")), .Names = 
c("id",
"name", "status"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
4L)), ad_units = list(structure(list(id = c("305636_default",
"10afdc90-0dad-013a-70af-0242ac120004"), name = c("Default",
"Thumbnail LOW"), format = structure(list(key = c("thumbnail",
"thumbnail"), label = c("Thumbnail", "Thumbnail")), .Names = c("key",
"label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), integration_type = 
  structure(list(
    key = c("standard_integration", "standard_integration"
    ), label = c("Standard Integration", "Standard Integration"
    )), .Names = c("key", "label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
   1:2)), .Names = c("id",
   "name", "format", "integration_type"), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = 
    1:2),
    structure(list(id = "305967_default", name = "Default",
        format = structure(list(key = "thumbnail", label = 
    "Thumbnail"), 
    .Names = c("key",
        "label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L),
        integration_type = structure(list(key = 
 "standard_integration",
            label = "Standard Integration"), .Names = c("key",
        "label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = 
c("id",
    "name", "format", "integration_type"), class = "data.frame",       
    row.names = 1L),
    structure(list(id = c("305966_default", "cb76d6a0-14ad-013a-af92- 
0242ac120004"
    ), name = c("Default", "Thumbnail LOW"), format = structure(list(
        key = c("thumbnail", "thumbnail"), label = c("Thumbnail",
        "Thumbnail")), .Names = c("key", "label"), class = 
   "data.frame", 
    row.names = 1:2),
        integration_type = structure(list(key = 
    c("standard_integration",
        "standard_integration"), label = c("Standard Integration",
        "Standard Integration")), .Names = c("key", "label"
        ), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)), .Names = c("id",
    "name", "format", "integration_type"), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = 1:2),
       structure(list(id = "305965_default", name = "Default",
        format = structure(list(key = "thumbnail", label = 
    "Thumbnail"), 
    .Names = c("key",
        "label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L),
        integration_type = structure(list(key = 
"standard_integration",
            
label = "Standard Integration"), .Names = c("key",
        "label"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = 
c("id",
   "name", "format", "integration_type"), class = "data.frame", 
   row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("asset_id",
   "asset_key", "app_api_key", "name", "bundle", "asset_type",
   "icon_url", "organization", "ad_units"), class = "data.frame", 
   row.names 
    = c(NA,
    4L))), .Names = c("dates", "countries", "formats", 
  "integration_types",
  "asset_types", "assets"))
>
```

What I need to get from a this is a data frame with the columns I need: dates, countries, asset$key and asset$name. I'm not sure If I'm also able to loop through the dates and get data for each date. I will later need to join this to a metrics data frame.

Comment: Please give us the result of `dput(dimensions)` instead of `str(dimensions)` so we can import the list into our R environment.

Comment: There is no info left on how dates should be connected to a particular country. Why you want to build one table of both data? Seems that they are unrelated...

Comment: @danloo I have edited to display dput(dimensions)

Comment: There is still no time related column in `dimensions$countries`. What date do you expect e.g. in a row having AT as country?

Comment: @danloo I was hoping to join the columns extract from this response to another data frame using the date and asset key. If the date is irrelevant here. Then I just want asset$, key, asset$name, country$key, country$label, organization$id, organization$name just to be able to enrich the data frame I join to this one.

Comment: Joining requires the same column appearing in both tables (e.g. the column date or any other column must be present in table assets and countries). This is not the case.

Comment: @danlooo Is there a way to just join asset_key and asset_name they are in the same data frame asset.

Comment: Joining is only to combine two *different* tables. Due to lack of linking information, you can not enrich your dataset any further.

Comment: @danloo Can I not from this reponse data extract asset_key and name from asset data frame?

Comment: This is what I tried dimensions <- rawToChar(dimensions)
dimensions <- fromJSON(dimensions)
dimensions <-(dimensions$assets)
dimensions_df <- dimensions[,c("assets_key","name"),]

Comment: Of course, you can do `dimensions$assets[,c("asset_key", "name")]` but this contains neither information about dates nor about countries as you wanted to have in the output.

Comment: @danlooo I figured I cant do much with this data frame after your comments so instead I used what I can get from this response to enrich my other data set with a merge.

Comment: I'm going to close this issue and open a new one to describe my issue as this has now changes completely. Thank you for your help on this. @danlooo